# Radio button: using [formControl] instead of [formControlName]

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

Let's assume I have the following form in an Angular component. The 3 form controls are radio buttons:

```js
form = new FormGroup({
    formControl: new FormControl(),
    formControl2: new FormControl(),
    formControlName: new FormControl()
});
```

When creating the radio buttons on the template, all the examples I've seen use `[formControlName]`, like so:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input
        type="radio"
        id="formControlNameTrue"
        [formControlName]="'formControlName'"
        [value]="true"
    >
    <label for="formControlNameTrue">FCN True</label>
</form>
```

However, I would like to use `[formControl]` instead:

```html
<input
    type="radio"
    id="formControlTrue"
    [formControl]="formControl"
    [value]="true"
>
<label for="formControlTrue">FC True</label>
```

The problem is that, when using 2 or more radio buttons with the `[formControl]` approach, the template does not display the values of the controls properly. In the following screenshot, I have selected "FC True" and then "FC2 False" with my mouse. Both of these controls have been built using `[formControl]`. This is the result:

[image: Form control behavior]

Please see the following stackblitz for the full code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3gbgbp.

**Is there any way of creating a radio button with `[formControl]` only? If not, is this expected behavior or it could be a bug?**

Comment: `[formControl]="form.get('formControl')"`, but **remove** the [value], the value is the value of the formControl

Comment: `[value]` is necessary to specify the value the FormControl will have when you select that radio button.

Comment: sorry, you're correct - i mixed checkbox with radio button, apologies

Comment: did you figure out what's going on?

Comment: @Chocho Unfortunately I haven't figured out. I went through Angular's code briefly but couldn't find anything useful. The RadioControlValueAccessor has a "input[type=radio][formControl]" selector, so it seems like it should work, but it does not

Comment: for future folks https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13243

Answer (score 0):

There is not need to use property binding try following code.

```
 form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    formControl: new FormControl(),
    formControl2: new FormControl(),
    formControlName: new FormControl()
  });

  get formControl() {
    return this.form.get("formControl");
  }

  get formControl2() {
    return this.form.get("formControl2");
  }

  get formControlName2() {
    return this.form.get("formControlName");
  }

  constructor() {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(changes => {
      console.log(changes);
    });
  }
```

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div>
        <input
      type="radio"
      id="formControlTrue"
      formControlName="formControl"
      [value]="true"
    >
        <label for="formControlTrue">FC True</label>
        <input
      type="radio"
      id="formControlFalse"
      formControlName="formControl"
      [value]="false"
    >
        <label for="formControlFalse">FC False</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input
      type="radio"
      id="formControl2True"
      formControlName="formControl2"
      [value]="true"
    >
        <label for="formControl2True">FC2 True</label>
        <input
      type="radio"
      id="formControl2False"
      formControlName="formControl2"
      [value]="false"
    >
        <label for="formControl2False">FC2 False</label>
    </div>
    <input
    type="radio"
    id="formControlNameTrue"
    formControlName="formControlName"
    [value]="true"
  >
    <label for="formControlNameTrue">FCN True</label>
    <input
    type="radio"
    id="formControlNameFalse"
    formControlName="formControlName"
    [value]="false"
  >
    <label for="formControlNameFalse">FCN False</label>
</form>
```

Comment: This is precisely what I'm trying to avoid, as I stated in the final question.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `formControlName` and use `[formControl]` instead?